# Continue capturing output after redirection

Tags: cmd

Okay, here's a toughie--   I'm capturing the output of cmd.exe just fine, reading from the pipe, yadda yadda yadda, but then a line in the cmd.exe batch file has the audacity to do:

dir err.txt >zz

.. that is, it's redirecting the output of the dir command, which is an internal command inside cmd.exe.

Problem is, this breaks my capturing of output!    I can't get anything from cmd.exe after that point.

Apparently to redirect standard output, it closes it, or somehow breaks it, and makes a new stdout to redirect the output.   And it never restores the old stdout handle.

Any ideas of how to track this output?

Answer (score 0):

you should call `dir err.txt` in a separate process. try `call dir err.txt >zz`

Comment: `call` won't use a separate process. You'd need `cmd /c "dir err.txt>zz"` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to modify the batch file, you may replace the inner redirection by a [TEE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29) command.

There are several ports to Windows (just google "[windows command tee](http://tinyurl.com/2uj4f7w)").

From Wikipedia:

In computing, tee is a command in various command-line interpreters (shells) 
such as Unix shells, 4DOS/4NT  and Windows PowerShell, which displays or pipes
the output of a command and copies it into a file or a variable